# Iteration on collection without using subreports

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to iterate a collection from a dataSource without using sub reports?

eg:- Data source Employee having a collection 'addressList'. For every employee there is multiple address such as permanent address, current address etc.

I want to to display the addresses of all the employees in a report without using a sub report to iterate the 'addressList'.

Comment: Do the addresses have to be shown in columns or can they just be concatenated strings in a text field, one address per line?

Comment: One entire address in concatenated as string in a text field.

eg:- EMP1
     Address 1
     Address 2
     Address 3

     EMP2
     Address 1
     Address 2
     Address 3

Comment: What approach are you using to fetch the list of Employee? Using query directly or using jrbeancollectiondatasource?

Comment: using JRBeanCollectionDataSource

Comment: Fetching the list of Employees using JRBeanCollectionDataSource

Answer (score 1):

You can use list component. [Jasper List component](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/list/index.html)
With list component, you can pass data using data source such as **JRBeanCollectionDataSource** and make iteration there. All the things that you can do in subreport's detail part, do there. But passing data from list component to main report is a bit tricky.